# How many clusters are in my samples? Combine two dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

data (for reproducible example)

```
df1 <- data.frame(cluster = c(1,2,3,1,1,2),variable = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'))

df1
        cluster  variable
1       1        a
2       2        b
3       3        c
4       1        d
5       1        e
6       2        f

df2 <- data.frame(variable = c('a','b','c','d','e','f'),ss4.U1 = c(0,0,0,0,5,6),ss4.U2 = c(1,1,1,0,5,0),gg3.U2 = c(5,0,0,0,0,0))
row.names(df2) <- df2$variable
df2 <- df2[ ,-1]

df2
  4ss4.U1 5ss4.U2 6gg3.U2
a      0      1      5
b      0      1      0
c      0      1      0
d      0      0      0
e      5      5      0
f      6      0      0
```

`df1` contains variables with their respective clusters. `df2` contains samples (the colnames) with their abundances of the variables (the rownames). I want a df that displays the abundances of the clusters (which consists of the variables) in the samples.

The result should look like this

```
samples 1 2 3
4ss4.U1  5 6 0
5ss4.U2  6 1 1
6gg3.U2  5 0 0
```

I think in the end, to get the number of the clusters in the samples, I can use the function `xtabs`.  But I do not know how to even get to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df2 %>% 
    rownames_to_column() %>% 
    right_join(df1, by = c("rowname" = "variable")) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = c(everything(), -rowname, -cluster), names_to = "sample") %>%
    group_by(cluster, sample) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = cluster, values_from = value)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'cluster' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  sample   `1`   `2`   `3`
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 gg3.U2     5     0     0
2 ss4.U1     5     6     0
3 ss4.U2     6     1     1
```

Comment: Thank you @iago. My real sample names are slightly different to the one I provided. "72DE.U2" for example. When I write this into your code, it displays an error (I think it is because of the number infront) I edited my question

Comment: @JORIS I updated my answer. I think the problem was in the selection of columns in `pivot_longer`.

Comment: It is a df but the columns are not numeric (as in the reprex) but characters

Comment: I'm not sure of understanding you. Have you tried my updated answer? Do you mean the values in the columns like `4ss4.U1` are characters? In that case, how the result should look like?

Comment: If you mean that they have character class but even though, they are numbers, then in my solution you could put `summarise(value = sum(as.numeric(value)))` instead of `summarise(value = sum(value))`

Comment: For future readers: ```df2[] <- lapply(df2, function(x) as.numeric(x))``` I switched the class to  numeric and succeeded with your solution. Thanks